# Double nested form in Rails - HTML fields empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Rails 4 app, I have three models:

Ordered list of challenges (position stored in `ListJoin` table):

```
class ChallengeList < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :list_joins, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :list_joins
```

ChallengeList-2-Challenge join model, containing list-challenge pairings and their positions in the challenge list.

```
class ListJoin < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope :order => 'position'
  belongs_to :challenge
  belongs_to :challenge_list
  acts_as_list :scope => :challenge_list
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :challenge
end
```

Challenge model, containing just a string field `description`.

```
class Challenge < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :list_joins
  has_many :challenge_lists, :through => :list_joins
```

I try to make a form in which I can edit a list's challenges and their positions at the same time:

```
= form_for @challenge_list do |f|
  -# ...fields for list...
  = f.fields_for :list_joins do |links_form|
     .field
       = links_form.number_field :position
     = links_form.fields_for :challenges do |challenge_form|
       .field
         -# The following fields will be empty
         = challenge_form.text_field :description
         = challenge_form.text_field :id -# Added to test I didn't make a typo on 'description'
```

When I test out the form, it renders okay, with the correct number of fields and everything, but the visible fields for `Challenge` (`:description` and `:id`) are empty, and it doesn't create a hidden field for the Challenge `id`! How can this be and can I fix it?

---

## EXAMPLE

Example of fields generated for a `Challenge` with id 9, as you can see the non-hidden input fields have no `value`, but the hidden id field does:

```
    <div class="field">
      <input id="challenge_list_list_joins_attributes_2_challenges_description" name="challenge_list[list_joins_attributes][2][challenges][description]" type="text">
      <input id="challenge_list_list_joins_attributes_2_challenges_id" name="challenge_list[list_joins_attributes][2][challenges][id]" type="text">
      <br>
    </div>
    <!-- This id field is for the join, but there is none for the description... -->
    <input id="challenge_list_list_joins_attributes_2_id" name="challenge_list[list_joins_attributes][2][id]" type="hidden" value="9">
```

Comment: Looking at the generated code, it seems that Rails assumes that a `ListJoin` has many challenges associated (e.g., `[2][challenges]`), but it only has one since it's `belongs_to`! Is this is a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may want a singular `challenge` here:

```
= links_form.fields_for :challenge do |challenge_form|
```

Comment: Oh my god, can't believe how I was blind to that.